# how to get data from rect in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've Rect with left, top, width and height. I would like to convert this to Path and get Data.

Is there any way to do it. I just want to check if two path overlap with each other and using this method.

Any advise would be appreciated. TIA!

```
    Geometry geo1 = parentShape.Data.Clone();
    geo1.Transform = parentShape.RenderTransform;
    Geometry geo2 = childShape.Data.Clone();
    geo2.Transform = childShape.RenderTransform;
    geo1.FillContainsWithDetail(geo2);
```

**EDIT:**
Please see my code. and let me know where I am wrong :(

```
 private bool CheckIfOverlapping(Rect rect1, Rect rect2, double rotation)
    {

        Geometry geo1 = RotatedRect(rect1, 0);

        Geometry geo2 = RotatedRect(rect2, rotation);

        var response1 = geo1.FillContainsWithDetail(geo2);
        var response2 = geo2.FillContainsWithDetail(geo1);
        var response3 = geo2.FillContains(geo1);
        var response4 = geo1.FillContains(geo2);

        return response4 || response3 || response1 == IntersectionDetail.Intersects || response2 == IntersectionDetail.Intersects;

    }

    private static Geometry RotatedRect(Rect rect, double rotation)
    {
        var centerX = (rect.Left + rect.Right) / 2;
        var centerY = (rect.Top + rect.Bottom) / 2;

        return new RectangleGeometry
        {
            Rect = rect,
            Transform = new RotateTransform(rotation, centerX, centerY),
        };
    }
    public Main()
    {
            var rect1 = new Rect(3546.5, 2734, 0, 0);
            var rect2 = new Rect(3510, 2731, 60, 52);
                Debug.WriteLine(CheckIfChildIsInsideParent(rect1, rect2, 180));

    }
```

Comment: You can create a RectangleGeometry from a Rect, and check this against another RectangleGeometry.

Comment: Or just call [`Rect.​Intersects​With(Rect)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.rect.intersectswith?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @Clemens thanks for your suggestion but my rectangle is rotated. so It has rotation angle of 60 degree. how would I create Rect wih rotational angle?

Comment: @Clemens: I have path with rotation angle and have Rect. My requirement is to check if both are overlapping with each other. Hope I am clear now.

Comment: You can set the Transform property of a RectangleGeometry.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Geometry from a rotated Rect by a method like this:

```
private static Geometry RotatedRect(Rect rect, double rotation)
{
    var centerX = (rect.Left + rect.Right) / 2;
    var centerY = (rect.Top + rect.Bottom) / 2;

    return new RectangleGeometry
    {
        Rect = rect,
        Transform = new RotateTransform(rotation, centerX, centerY)
    };
}
```

Try it like this:

```
var rect1 = new Rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
var rect2 = new Rect(200, 100, 100, 100);

var geo1 = RotatedRect(rect1, 45);
var geo2 = RotatedRect(rect2, 45);

Debug.WriteLine(geo1.FillContainsWithDetail(geo2));
```

Comment: it returns IntersectionDetails.Empty

Comment: For me it returns `Intersects`.

Comment: This is the values for me.  

var rect1 = new Rect(3546.5,2734,0,0);
var rect2 = new Rect(3510,2731,60,52);

var geo1 = RotatedRect(rect1, 0);
var geo2 = RotatedRect(rect2, 180);

Debug.WriteLine(geo1.FillContainsWithDetail(geo2));
Debug.WriteLine(geo2.FillContainsWithDetail(geo1));

Comment: You do realize that your first Rect has zero width and height? It will obviously not intersect with anything.

Comment: In order to test whether a geometry contains a single point, use [Fill​Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.geometry.fillcontains?view=netframework-4.8). But why are you then asking for how to "*check if two path overlap with each other*"?

Comment: Thanks, Pls see my code I added in my original question. Regarding why I was asking for path beacsue I have a path (shape of rectangle and rotated) and a normal rectangle. I did not know how to check if they are overlapping so I thought I would make normal rect into path and then check overlapping.

Comment: You haven't carefully read my answer. Otherwise you would have noticed that the RotateTransform's center point is specified in absolute coordinates, not relative. Besides that, when I mentioned the FillContains method, I was of course referring to the [overload that takes a Point argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.geometry.fillcontains?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Media_Geometry_FillContains_System_Windows_Point_), not a Geometry. You are using the wrong one.

Comment: You are using the wrong FillContains method. Try `geo2.FillContains(rect1.TopLeft);`. As already said, empty RectangleGeometries do not intersect.

Comment: Also note that a 180° rotation of a Rect around its center is redundant.

Comment: Yes 180 degree is redundant just an example, I would be getting different angles for different rectangles.